# Porque este grupo de captura no consigue capturar la subcadena en medio de los parentesis de captura?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, regex

```
import re

input_text = "((PERS) Tomás), ((PERS) Kyara Gomez) y ((PERS) Camila) fueron a ((VERB) caminar) y ((VERB) saltar) ((PL_ADVB) en la montaña)(2023_-_02_-_05(00:00 am))((PL_ADVB) ((NOUN)en el parque amplio y naranja) por el otoño)"

#Initialize empty sub-lists
list_of_persons = []

#patterns with capture groups:
capture_pattern_persons = r"\(\(PERS\)" + r'((?:[\w,;.]\s*)+)' + r"\)"

info_list = []  # Initialize the empty list of list

#I add the lists that should already be complete to the main list
list_of_persons = re.findall(capture_pattern_persons, input_text)
info_list.append(list_of_persons)

print(repr(info_list)) #print the output main list with the elements in the lists
```

El patrón del grupo de captura de esta regex `r"\(\(PERS\)" + r'((?:[\w,;.]\s*)+)' + r"\)"` no captura ninguna de las coincidencias que estan entre paréntesis `(` `)`

`[[]]`

Debería obtener esto como output:

`[ ["Tomás", "Kyara Gomez", "Camila"] ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicación:

La expresión regular dice que (PERS) viene seguido del nombre sin un espacio intermedio.

Solución:

```
capture_pattern_persons = r"\(\(PERS\) ((?:[\w,;.]\s*)+)\)"
```

produce:

```
[['Tomás', 'Kyara Gomez', 'Camila']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```